# I am unable to plot below data using python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have 4(a,x,y,z) columns of which 2nd column is having the data of 1st column only after the decimal places.
I am able to plot the curve using 2nd, 3rd, and 4th but need is to use the first column in place of 2nd.
I am not getting the expected outcome
Data:

```
 2457455.1457512  .1457512  18.1475 0.0345905 
 2457455.1492267  .1492267  18.866  0.0523474
 2457455.1527023  .1527023  19.676  0.078232
 2457455.1561779  .1561779  19.4285 0.0822207
 2457455.1596534  .1596534  18.531  0.0434684
 2457455.1631289  .1631289  17.9085 0.0306676
```

I tried to relocate x, thinking that might help, sharing the expected image :

[[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LntG4.png][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LntG4.png)

Code I have used to get expected outcome:

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(line,x,y)
yfit = line(x,*popt)
print(x,yfit)
print ("a =", popt[0], "+/-", pcov[0,0]**0.5)
print( "b =", popt[1], "+/-", pcov[1,1]**0.5)
print ("c =", popt[2], "+/-", pcov[2,2]**0.5)
plt.errorbar(x,y, yerr=z, ls = "none", marker = 'o', color ="blue")
plt.errorbar(x,yfit, color='green')
plt.xlabel("HJD(2457455+)", size = 15)
plt.ylabel("R(mag)",  size = 15)
#plt.legend(loc = 1)
plt.savefig("curve_fit.pdf")
plt.show()
```

Can anyone guide me on how can I plot using the 1st column.

Comment: What do you want to plot? `y` with respect to `a` and `z` with respect to `a`? And what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @mck,   can you help?

Comment: a as x-axis, y as y-axis, problem is X being too large compared to y and I am unable to plot the same.

Comment: I still don't see the problem. `plt.errorbar(a,y, yerr=z)` (with `a,x,y,z` as the columns defined in the question, e.g., `a=[2457455.1457512, 2457455.1492267, 2457455.1527023, 2457455.1561779, 2457455.1596534, 2457455.1631289]`) works fine for me. Your questions is missing the definition of `line` so I can't try the fitting function.